# Node mailer errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend, nodemailer

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 name:"www.rolester.com",
 service:"smtp",
 port: 27017,
 auth: {
   user: "aladi09@rolester.com",
   pass: "alandiv09"
   }
```

when i try this code i get his error

```
Error: Greeting never received
```

and when i change the port to my domain email port which is 587 i get this error

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587
```

and when i try to turn secure to true like that .`secure : true`

i get this error

```
[Error: 68390000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:
```

]
any solution ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
        port: process.env.HOST_PORT,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    })
```

```
use this format
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that that is not a smtp server so it can't send emails